# Is there a way to query Hazelcast's map's dirty entries?

Tags: java, hazelcast

Hazelcast map marks the entries as dirty which has been updated. And later on writes these with the writer provided. Is there a way to query those "dirty" entries.

Why I need this?

I am writing a custom writer, which I want to control when it is called and how many time etc.. As of now I have to keep a copy of data which is separate from the map's entries.

Answer (score 0):

How about `IMap.getEntryView` ? It has last update time